# Interpolation with constraint on singular values of differentials

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, differential-geometry, optimization, numerical-methods

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable map. At any point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, I define (for the lack of knowing a better term) the 'singularity' $S(f,x)$ of $f$ at $x$ to be
$$ S(f,x) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (\log \sigma_i)^2} $$
where the sum is taken over the singular values $\sigma_i$ of the matrix $df_x$. Define the 'total singularity' $S(f)$ as
$$ S(f) = \int S(f,x) \text{ } dx $$
I am given a collection of pairs $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_k,y_k)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$, and I would like to find the differentiable map $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ which minimizes the total singularity. My question is: Is there an easy characterization of $f$?

A linear approximation of $E(f, x)$ would be
$$ E(f, x) \approx \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n (\sigma_i - 1)^2} $$
Perhaps, finding $f$ with respect to this simplified singularity measure is easier. I would be interested in this as well.

Comment: The answer, if it exists, is very far from being unique. You can add constants, multiply by bump functions supported away from the nodes, etc... So, this problem is seriously underdetermined. You may consider requesting more constraints to make it more solvable.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Is this still the case if you impose strict boundary conditions?

Comment: Yes. If you require, say, that $\lim_{\lvert x \rvert \to \infty} f(x)=0$ you cannot add constants anymore, but you can still multiply by bump functions. Have you got any idea of a possible shape of the functions you need? Can you prescribe them in, say, some finite dimensional vector space? For example, can your functions be sums of Gaussians or something like that?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I'm not sure if I understand your point. Consider the one-dimensional case. Then $S(f) = \int (\log |df/dx|)^2 dx$. You'd therefore like $df/dx$ to be close to $1$. Introducing a bump would just increase $S(f)$.

Comment: Oh, yes. For some reason my mind registered that integral as a finite sum. Then the bump remark is not there and the boundary condition at infinity is enough to remove underdeterminacy. I guess that your example with $n=1$ is the right starting point. The first thing I would do is to determine the Euler-Lagrange equation that a minimizer (if it exists) should satisfy.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for the suggestion. Preliminary computations with Sympy seems to indicate that the Euler-Lagrange equation in Cartesian coordinates gets extremely complicated already at $n = 2$. (But I should add that I'm not confident about my math.)

Comment: And what about the $n=1$ case, without the square root, as in [your previous comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4555015/interpolation-with-constraint-on-singular-values-of-differentials?noredirect=1#comment9582013_4555015)? That does not look too terrible and it could give precious hints concerning the nature of the extremizers. The higher-dimensional case is most probably not explicitly solvable anyway.

Comment: Without the square root the Euler-Lagrange equation just seems to want $f'' = 0$ which I guess yields piecewise-linear interpolation. Do you have any pointers for numerical methods for higher-dimensional extremizers?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not much more to say. If you really find a piecewise-linear extremizer, that means that extremizers do not exist: for your functional to be well-defined the argument must be differentiable. It may well be that extremizers never exist also in the general case. But this seems like a really difficult question.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for your help. I'm working on finding a minimizer using a finite-difference method which so far seems to be working well.